# How to correctly apply a has_many relationship with an order by in Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-6, has-many, model-associations

I am creating a User model in Rails 6 to mirror a model that exists in a separate project.
There is a has_many relationship that is causing some problems.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :activation_histories, inverse_of: :user , => { order "created_at  DESC"} 
end
```

The project I am basing this on used Rails 3.2 and worked successfully like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
       has_many :activation_histories, inverse_of: :user, order: "created_at desc" 
end
```

I can see from the official documentation the example using an order by looks as so

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, -> { order "date_confirmed DESC" }
end
```

I get an error that it is expecting '=>' rather than '->' when I run it as so, but when I use '=>' I am getting

```
app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected =>
app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting `end'
app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected =>
app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting `end'
app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected =>
app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting `end'
```

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails and am not sure where I am going wrong here or how to proceed.
Removing the inverse_of has no effect on the errors I  am seeing.

Any advice on how to correctly use this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```rb
has_many :activation_histories, inverse_of: :user , -> { order "created_at  DESC"}
```

to

```rb
has_many :activation_histories, -> { order "created_at  DESC"} , inverse_of: :user
```

Your `scope` should be your second argument.
https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord%2FAssociations%2FClassMethods:has_many

Comment: Should be -> , fat arrow is not used for lambdas in ruby

Comment: Hi thanks for this, putting the scope as the second argument worked, and allowed me to use -> correctly. I think I had tried to change the order but maintained the fat arrow.
Really appreciate it.